# Download older version of Notenote onto my laptop

Tags: app-store, onenote

I would like to download and install Onenote 2010 to my aging laptop.

I run OSX 10.7.5 and cannot update it. Even if I could, I would not do so.

I'd like to try MicroSoft Onenote, but on the App Store, I cannot find a "download older version" option. When I click the download button in iOS, it asks me if I'd like to download an older version, but not here.

Answer (score -1):

The only version of OneNote that is available for Mac OSX is available through the app store.

There is no version of OneNote 2010 that works on Mac.